# Bulk query help

Tags: api, query, java, bulk-api, bulk

I am trying to get my bulk query up and running to get data from our salesforce account.  I have looked up a lot of examples since salesforce fails to give a java example for a bulk query.  None of them seem to work however, even though it seems like it should be super simple.  I have tried implementing from this open code:

[Exporting Data to CSV file via Bulk API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24081/exporting-data-to-csv-file-via-bulk-api?rq=1)

And after changing the user and pass I am getting and invalid login for either invalid username, password, security token, or user locked out. I have triple checked and my credentials are all good and we are not locked out.  Is there something special I need to do for the security token?  I was under the impression the sforce library takes care of that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For this API case, the password you supply has to be the normal password with the security token appended. You have to do that. Try that.

See the "Creating an Enterprise WSDL Application" section of [Introduction to the Force.com Web Services Connector](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Introduction_to_the_Force.com_Web_Services_Connector).

Comment: I have it set that way.  Thanks for the link It looks like better code for it.  However, I am getting the following error from implementing the partner services connect (its the only thing in maven it looks like)     com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Failed to send request to https://login-blitz01.soma.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/34.0  Any ideas?

Comment: @Chadvador The normal domain for the login is https://test.salesforce.com for sandboxes or https://login.salesforce.com for production or developer edition orgs. Is https://login-blitz01.soma.salesforce.com something you are specifying in your code?